# Fastest way to find all pairs of close numbers in a Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, vectorization

Say I have a Numpy array of `N = 10` random float numbers:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(99)
N = 10
arr = np.random.uniform(0., 10., size=(N,))
print(arr)

out[1]: [6.72278559 4.88078399 8.25495174 0.31446388 8.08049963 
         5.6561742 2.97622499 0.46695721 9.90627399 0.06825733]
```

I want to find all **unique** pairs of numbers that are not different from each other more than a tolerance `tol = 1.` (i.e. absolute difference <= 1). Specifically, I want to get all unique pairs of indexes. The indexes of each close pair should be sorted, and all close pairs should be sorted by the first index. I managed to write the following working code:

```
def all_close_pairs(arr, tol=1.):
    res = set()
    for i, x1 in enumerate(arr):
        for j, x2 in enumerate(arr):
            if i == j:
                continue
            if np.isclose(x1, x2, rtol=0., atol=tol):
                res.add(tuple(sorted([i, j])))
    res = np.array(list(res))
    return res[res[:,0].argsort()]

print(all_close_pairs(arr, tol=1.))

out[2]: [[1 5]
         [2 4]
         [3 7]
         [3 9]
         [7 9]]
```

However, in reality I have an array of `N = 1000` numbers, and my code becomes extremely slow due to the nested for loops. I believe there are much more efficient ways to do this with Numpy vectorization. Does anyone know the fastest way to do this in Numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a solution with pure numpy operations. It seems pretty fast on my machine, but I don't know what kind of speed we're looking for.

```py
def all_close_pairs(arr, tol=1.):
    N = arr.shape[0]
    # get indices in the array to consider using meshgrid
    pair_coords = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))).T
    # filter out pairs so we get indices in increasing order
    pair_coords = pair_coords[pair_coords[:, :, 0] < pair_coords[:, :, 1]]
    # compare indices in your array for closeness
    is_close = np.isclose(arr[pair_coords[:, 0]], arr[pair_coords[:, 1]], rtol=0, atol=tol)
    return pair_coords[is_close, :]
```

Answer (score 6):

One efficient solution is to first **sort the input values** using `index = np.argsort()`. Then, you can generate the sorted array using `arr[index]`, and then iterate over the close values in **quasi-linear time** if the number of pair is small on a fast *contiguous array*. If the number of pair is big, then the complexity is **quadratic** due to the quadratic number of pair generated. THe resulting complexity is: `O(n log n + m)` where `n` is the size of the input array and `m` is the number of pair produced.

To find values close to each other, one efficient way is to iterate over the value using **Numba**. Indeed, while it might be possible in Numpy, it will likely not be efficient due to the variable number of value to be compared. Here is an implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('int32[:,::1](float64[::1], float64)')
def findCloseValues(arr, tol):
    res = []
    for i in range(arr.size):
        val = arr[i]
        # Iterate over the close numbers (only once)
        for j in range(i+1, arr.size):
            # Sadly neither np.isclose or np.abs are implemented in Numba so far
            if max(val, arr[j]) - min(val, arr[j]) >= tol:
                break
            res.append((i, j))
    if len(res) == 0: # No pairs: we need to help Numpy to know the shape
        return np.empty((0, 2), dtype=np.int32)
    return np.array(res, dtype=np.int32)
```

Finally, the indices need to be update to reference the indices in the unsorted array and not the sorted one. You can do that using `index[result]`.

Here is the resulting code:

```py
index = arr.argsort()
result = findCloseValues(arr[index], 1.0)
print(index[result])
```

Here is the result (the order is not the same as in the question but you could sort it if needed):

```
array([[9, 3],
       [9, 7],
       [3, 7],
       [1, 5],
       [4, 2]])
```

---

### Improving the complexity of the algorithm

If you need a faster algorithm, then you can use another output format: you can for each input value provide the min/max range of values close to the target input value. To find the range, you can use a binary search (see: `np.searchsorted`) on the sorted array. The resulting algorithm runs in `O(n log n)`. However, you cannot get the indices in the unsorted array since the range would be non contiguous.

### Benchmark

Here are performance results on a random input with 1000 items and a tolerance of 1.0, on my machine:

```
Reference implementation:   ~17000 ms             (x 1)
Angelicos' implementation:    1773 ms           (x ~10)
Rivers' implementation:        122 ms           (x 139)
Rchome's implementation:        20 ms           (x 850)
Chris' implementation:           4.57 ms       (x 3720)
This implementation:             0.67 ms      (x 25373)
```

Comment: I don't know if you can beat an `O(N^2)` algorithm. In the end, there are up to `O(N^2)` pairs, and even if you sort it, you can't avoid having to construct the output pairs. Vectorization like numpy and numba do will help though.

Comment: Indeed. Good point. I forgot that the number of pair is `N*(N+1)/2` in the worst case ^^". I edited the question to fix this point and provided a solution to reduce the complexity (assuming the output format can be adapted). I will probably check the performance of the algorithms ;) .

Answer (score 4):

A bit late but an all numpy solution:

```
import numpy as np

def close_enough( arr, tol = 1 ): 
    result = np.where( np.triu(np.isclose( arr[ :, None ], arr[ None, : ], rtol = 0.0, atol = tol ), 1)) 
    return np.swapaxes( result, 0, 1 )
```

Expanded to explain what is happening

```
def close_enough( arr, tol = 1 ):
    bool_arr = np.isclose( arr[ :, None ], arr[ None, : ], rtol = 0.0, atol = tol )
    # is_close generates a square array after comparing all elements with all elements.  

    bool_arr = np.triu( bool_arr, 1 ) 
    # Keep the upper right triangle, offset by 1 column. i.e. zero the main diagonal 
    # and all elements below and to the left.

    result = np.where( bool_arr )  # Return the row and column indices for Trues
    return np.swapaxes( result, 0, 1 ) # Return the pairs in rows rather than columns
```

With N = 1000, arr = an array of floats

```
%timeit close_enough( arr, tol = 1 )                                                                              
14.1 ms ± 28.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [19]: %timeit all_close_pairs( arr, tol = 1 )                                                                           
54.3 ms ± 268 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

(close_enough( arr, tol = 1) == all_close_pairs( arr, tol = 1 )).all()                                            
# True
```

Comment: Nice, I like this better than my own answer. I didn't know about `np.triu`, which was what I was trying to accomplish with `pair_coords[pair_coords[:, :, 0] < pair_coords[:, :, 1]]`. Also, that's a neat trick to use the new axis and broadcasting to get all of the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code has O(n*n) (quadratic) complexity.
To lower complexity, you can try to sort items first:

```py
def all_close_pairs(arr, tol=1.):
    res = set()
    arr = sorted(enumerate(arr), key=lambda x: x[1])
    for (idx1, (i, x1)) in enumerate(arr):
        for idx2 in range(idx1-1, -1, -1):
            j, x2 = arr[idx2]
            if not np.isclose(x1, x2, rtol=0., atol=tol):
                break
            indices = sorted([i, j])
            res.add(tuple(indices))
    return np.array(sorted(res))
```

However, this would only work if range of your values much larger than tolerance.

You could improve this further by using `2 pointers` strategy but overall complexity would remain same.

Answer (score 1):

You could first create combinations with itertools.combinations:

```
def all_close_pairs(arr, tolerance):
    pairs = list(combinations(arr, 2))
    indexes = list(combinations(range(len(arr)), 2))
    all_close_pairs_indexes = [indexes[i] for i,pair in enumerate(pairs) if abs(pair[0] - pair[1]) <=  tolerance]
    return all_close_pairs_indexes
```

Now, for N=1000, you will have to compare only 499500 pairs instead of 1 million.

**How it works:**

- We first create the pairs via itertools.combinations.
- Then, we create the list of their indexes.
- We use a list comprehension instead of a for loop, for speed reasons.
- In this comprehension, we iterate all pairs, using `enumerate` so we can get the index of the pair, we compute the absolute difference of the numbers in the pair, and if check if it's less or equal than the `tolerance`.
- If the absolute difference is less or equal than `tolerance`, we get the indexes of the pairs's numbers via the list of indexes, and add them to our final list.